# A question on frobenius group.

Tags: permutations, frobenius-groups

I have to do this question in my assignment...[image]

I studied frobenius group from Permutation groups by Dixon and this is the given definition in it for Frobenius group so I guess I have to assume this definition which is in Rotman that a group is frobenius iff it contains a proper subgroup $H \neq 1$ s.t. $H \cap gHg^{-1}=1$ for all $g \notin H$.  How should I proceed now.

Comment: Ask what does the assignment's writer mean by Frobenius Groups.

Comment: oops it is due tommorow.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Then start your assignments earlier. And maybe go to class so you know what definitions they are using.